# How to connect a local repository to remote repository in bitbucket?

Tags: git, connection, bitbucket

I have created a branch of the master repository on Bitbucket.
But I have cloned the master repository on my local system.

But I want to push all the changes on the branch which I have created on remote.

How do I do that?

Please help out.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if what you are saying makes total sense, but if I understand you correctly:
You created a branch remotely. You then made changes to your local copy which was on the master branch. Now you want to push the changes you made to the remote branch?
If this is the case, then you could create a local branch:

```
git checkout -b <local-branch-with-changes>
```

Then add and commit your changed files.
Then do a checkout on the branch you created remotely.

```
git checkout <your-remote-branchname>
```

And merge your local branch with the remote, commit and push to origin.

see: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

you may have to do

```
git fetch --all
```

before. You can check which branches you have available with

```
git branch --all
```